# Why are we not checking both condition in "and" of if statement , and in checking both condition in "or" of If condition?

Tags: c++, if-statement

[image: W]

[image]

**CAN YOU PLEASE EXPLAIN IN DETAIL.**
Why are we not checking both condition in "and" of if statement , and in checking both condition in "or" of If condition?

Why in first question x= 11, y=20, is printed.
While in second question x=11, y=21, is printed.

Comment: Not sure if this is a SO question, that is some basic programming stuff you can read in any basic book / prob blogposts, too.
Look up short circuit evaluation

Comment: Btw. please, don't post code as images. (See [ask]: _**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.**_ (emphasize not mine).)

Comment: Ok. I will keep in mind for future doubt.

Answer (score 1):

when you have an expression like `A || B` and A is true, there is no need to evaluate B. The outcome of the whole expression will be true. Something similar goes for `A && B`.

That means that you must not put assignments or the like in your expression in the way you do, since they can be short circuited. So the ++y is dangerous stuff: you cannot rely on it being executed.